# Diferença entre ?. e ?? em C#

Tags: c#, operadores, null

Eu olhei a documentação da [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) mas ainda sim achei um pouco confuso, as principais coisas que eu consegui abstrair foram:

- **"?."** - é um operador nulo condicional e testa o valor do operando esquerdo para nulo antes de executar um acesso de membro. **Achei esse bem confuso**
- **"??"** - é um operador de coalescência nula, ele retorna o operando esquerdo se o operando não for nulo; caso contrário, ele retornará o operando direito..

Aparentemente eles apresentam ter funções muito similares, queria saber qual é a real diferença entre eles.

E porque não posso utilizar eles dentro da condição de um `IF` ou um `WHILE`?

Comment: Coalescência nula é mais fácil de entender. Se o lado esquerdo for nulo, retorne o que está do lado direito. Exemplo: `string nome = null ?? "jeff";`, qual será o conteúdo da variável `nome`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

O `?.` é para evitar comparações do tipo `obj != null ? obj.prop : null`, ou seja, ele verificará se o que tem antes da interrogação é diferente de `null`, por exemplo:

```
//Se qualquer obj for nulo, ele retornará nulo, caso contrário retornará prop
return obj?.objFilho?.objNeto?.prop;

//Equivalente a
if(obj != null && obj.objFilho != null && obj.objFilho.objNeto != null)
{
    return obj.objFilho.objNeto.prop;
}
return null;
```

Já o `??` serve para, caso o valor retornado seja nulo, ele retornará um valor padrão, por exemplo:

```
int? a = null;
int b = a ?? 1; //Se a for nulo, ele retorna 1
```

É possível, inclusive combinar esses operadores da seguinte forma:

```
var prop =  obj?.objFilho?.objNeto?.prop ?? 0;
```

Você não consegue usar eles em laços condicionais ou laços de repetição porque eles **não retornam um valor booleano**, mas sim valores em comparação com `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Veja a seguinte estrutura de exemplo:

```
class Pai
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Filho Filho { get; set; }
}

class Filho
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Se você executar o código abaixo, receberá uma exception de referência nula, pois estará tentando acessar o atributo de uma instância que não foi declarada

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var pai = new Pai { Nome = "Teste Pai" };
        var nomeDoFilho = pai.Filho.Nome;

        Console.WriteLine(nomeDoFilho);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Agora, se você utilizar o `?.`, será verificado se o objeto não é nulo antes de acessar a propriedade para a atribuição à variável.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var pai = new Pai { Nome = "Teste Pai" };
        var nomeDoFilho = pai.Filho?.Nome;

        Console.WriteLine(nomeDoFilho);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

E aproveitando a coalescência `??`, comentada pelo colega, você pode inclusive já realizar um tratamento para a ocorrência.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var pai = new Pai { Nome = "Teste Pai" };
        var nomeDoFilho = pai.Filho?.Nome ?? "Não possui filho";

        Console.WriteLine(nomeDoFilho);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```